# Evaluate the angle between two curves at their intersection: $y=x^2+1, x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the angle between two curves at their intersection: $y=x^2+1, x^2+y^2=1$

---

Actually  don't know what the problem means

Comment: Both equations have a corresponding graph. These graphs intersect at a unique point. What is the angle between them, or equivalently **the angle between their tangent lines at that point**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle between two curves at the point of intersection is defined as the angle between their tangents at that point.

So **hint** find the point(s) of intersection and the slopes of the tangents at that/those points.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation defines an upward looking parabola with its lowest point at (0, 1). The second equation defines a unit (i.e. r=1) circumference with the center at (0, 0). Quite obviously, they intersect in a single point where both tangents are horizontal. Hence, the angle between them is k*pi, where k is an integer.

You can also prove this analytically by solving the system of two equations to find their intersection point, then calculating the tangents at that point, and finding the angle between them.